# Como calcular el mayor numero que se repite en un array?

Tags: java

Eso basicamente, ya tengo los valores de las variables las cuales son aleatorias. Lo que quisiera saber es como sacar el numero que mas se repite. De ser posible evitar el uso de maps, list y eso, solo algo "simple".

```
    int num[]=new int[15];
    int control=0;

    private void btnPoblarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
        num[i]=(int)(Math.random()*9);
    }
    control=1;
    }                                         

    private void btnMostrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if(control==1){
        txtTArea.setText("");
        for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
            txtTArea.append(num[i]+" ");
        }   
    }else{
        txtTArea.setText("Debe poblar el vector");
    }
    }
    private void btnRepetidoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    }
```

Comment: Siempre habra q usar algun tipo de estructura, no se resuelve con magia

Comment: los numeros aleatorios son de 0 a 9? o es otro rango

Answer (score 0):

Seguro que tendrás que mejorar el código a continuación, por ejemplo, no sé qué pasará si hay dos números que se repiten la misma cantidad de veces, pero es un buen comienzo ya que funciona y responde a la base de tu pregunta. .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // solo creación del vector con números aleatorios
    final Random R = new Random();
    int[] num = new int[15];
    System.out.print("Los numeros son: ");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++) {
        num[i] = R.nextInt(9);
        System.out.print(num[i] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    // fin de la creación
    
    
    // variables de soporte
    int counter = 0;
    int current = 0;
    
    int lastmaxcounter = 0;
    int lastmax = 0;
    
    
    // aquí recorreré todo el vector, para cada posición en la que estoy ahora, 
    // volveré a recorrer el vector buscando números repetidos, pero solo iré desde 
    // la posición actual en adelante, si no lo hago haga j = i + 1 para iniciar 
    // el segundo ciclo, cada número será alertado como repetido
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++) {
        counter = 0; 
        current = 0;
        
        // Inicie el bucle, pero solo en la siguiente posición del vector en adelante
        for (int j = i+1 ; j < 15 ; j++) {
            // Verifique si hay una repetición, si es así, verifique si el 
            // control ya se hizo y solo agrega el número de repetición, si 
            // es el primer encuentro, cree el control.
            if (num[i] == num[j]) {
                if (lastmax == num[i]) {
                    lastmaxcounter++;
                } else {
                    current = num[i];
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Después de recorrer los vectores, verifique si el número encontrado en 
        // esta posición se repite más que el número encontrado en una posición anterior, 
        // si es así, modifique el número más repetido; de lo contrario, no haga nada, 
        // simplemente continúe con el siguiente ciclo.
        if (current > 0 && current != lastmax && counter > lastmaxcounter) {
            lastmax = current;
            lastmaxcounter = counter;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Numero que mas repite: " + lastmax + " y repite " + lastmaxcounter + " veces ");        
    
}
```